# Testing controllers with local variables using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, stub

I'm new to Rspec and fairly new to RoR. With that said, I've exhausted all my options trying to get this to work. I have a variable in a method to create a `User` in the `create` action of my `UserController.rb`. This variable gets the data from an authentication method. Then, I use this local variable, which is a response from an API call, to create the user according to the variables parameters. I've tried everything to my knowledge of Rspec, which is not much, without luck. I keep getting errors because the data variable is nil since I stub/mock the method and the variable.

If anyone could help me figure out how to test this or link me to a good tutorial (I've read a bunch) on how to do this, I would really appretiate it.

Here's my code:

#### users_controller.rb

```
def get_google_data
  ...
  data = response.parsed #OAuth2 

  @id = data['id']
  @email = data['email']
  @fname = data['given_name']
  @lname = data['family_name']
end

def create
  get_google_data
  puts "Got google data"
  puts @id
  if !@id.nil?
    puts "data is not nil"
    @user = User.find_by_google_id(@id)
    puts @user

    if @user.nil?
      puts "inside user condition"
      @user = User.new(:email => @email, :google_id => @id,
                       :first_name => @fname,
                       :last_name => @lname)

      if @user.save
        render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
      else
        render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      puts "ended in the right Place"
      render json: @user, location: @user
    end
  end
end
```

#### users_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "should not create duplicate user" do
  it "returns user object that was previously created" do
    @user = mock_model(User, :google_id=>1)
    #controller.should_receive(:get_google_data).and_return(:true)
    controller.instance_variable_set(:@id, 1)
    User.stub!(:find_by_google_id).with(1).and_return(@user)

    post :create
    @user.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

I'm having 2 problems.

1. The test fails because I cannot control the data in `data['id']` and the following assignments.

   ```
   Failure/Error: post :create
    NoMethodError:
      undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:109:in `get_google_data'
    # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:118:in `create'
    # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   ```
2. The call to return `@user` gives me a circular reference error:

   ```
   2) UsersController should not create duplicate user returns user object that was previously created
    Failure/Error: post :create
    ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError:
      object references itself
    # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:141:in `create'
    # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   ```

Comment: Where is the code that generates the `response`, in the line: `data = response.parsed`?

You might want to wrap that up in a class that you own, if it's from a third-party and then mock that object.  Then, you can control what gets returned so that you won't have error #1.

Comment: Yeah, this was code written when I first started writing ruby. I now have a better understanding of how everything works and whatnot.